# How to group by month and year from Date field using Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I need to group by month or year in the Date column of the table. and I currently used the group function also. I need to add an additional group condition. Is it possible having two grouping conditions and grouping monthly, yearly in Sequelize? Please if someone is using it, share it with me.

```
Table
-----------------------------------------------------------
| bulk_id |    date    | grade_GL | gross_weight | lot_id |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   100   | 2020-10-02 |    A     | 100          |  1000  |
|   100   | 2020-10-02 |    B     | 120          |  1002  |
|   100   | 2020-10-02 |    C     | 140          |  1004  |
|   101   | 2020-10-22 |    A     | 210          |  1006  |
|   101   | 2020-10-22 |    B     | 230          |  1008  |
|   101   | 2020-10-22 |    C     | 250          |  1010  |
|   102   | 2020-11-03 |    A     | 110          |  1013  |
|   102   | 2020-11-03 |    B     | 130          |  1015  |
|   102   | 2020-11-03 |    C     | 200          |  1017  |
|   103   | 2020-11-23 |    A     | 220          |  1019  |
|   103   | 2020-11-23 |    B     | 240          |  1021  |
|   103   | 2020-11-23 |    C     | 150          |  1023  |

Expected Result
------------------------------------------------
| grade_GL |    month    | sum_of_gross_weight |
------------------------------------------------
|    A     |   October   |         310         |
|    B     |   October   |         350         |
|    C     |   October   |         390         |
|    A     |   November  |         330         |
|    B     |   November  |         370         |
|    C     |   November  |         350         |
```

** When bulk_Id 100,101,102,103 is given expected result should be above table.

Here is my current Sequeilize:

```js
const gradeWiseTotalLots = await Lot.findAll({
                attributes: ['grade_GL', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('gross_weight')), 'total_Gross_weight'],],
                where: {BulkBulkId: bulk_id_ele.dataValues.bulk_id,},
                group: ['grade_GL']
            });
```

Select statement I would expect is:

```
SELECT `grade_GL`, sum(`gross_weight`) AS `total_Gross_weight` FROM `Lots` AS `Lot` WHERE `Lot`.`BulkBulkId` = 103 GROUP BY `grade_GL`,`month`;
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY month if you don't SELECT that column?

Comment: what I want is to get a sum of gross weight column by grouping 'grade_GL' and 'date' column as month-wise.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) Simplify if possible. [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh I have edited the question. please look it